# query to select row with value in a column but not in other

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-performance

I have written below query:

```
select case when edd.is_percent='Y' 
               then (((edd.dis_value/100) * c.paid_amount) - c.amount) 
            else (edd.dis_value - c.amount) 
       end as profit 
from  used_balance_detail ubd 
inner 
join  service_category_service_type scst 
on    scst.id = ubd.service_category_service_type_id 
inner 
join  service_category sc 
on    sc.id = scst.service_category_id 
inner 
join  epay_discount_details edd 
on    sc.id = edd.service_category_id 
inner 
join  commission c 
on    c.used_balance_detail_id = ubd.id 
and   c.subscriber_id not in  (select distinct c.discount_given_to_id 
                               from   used_balance_detail ubd 
                               inner join commission c 
                               on    c.used_balance_detail_id = ubd.id 
                               where c.discount_given_to_id is not null)
and   scst.merchant_type = 'R' group by ubd.id asc;
```

This gives the desired result for lesser data. But i have rows above 5000 & this becomes too slow to get result. 
Is this query can be modified to give faster result?

Comment: No need for that distinct in the sub-query.

Comment: You are grouping by `ubd.id`, yet will have possibly multiple `edd` records, so which of those do you expect to be selected? You are using a lousy, non-SQL-standard feature of MySql that just picks whatever it likes. I don't think these results can be meaningful. You should specify which `edd` record you want to get the info from, or -- if you want all of them aggregated -- specify an aggregation function (like `avg` or `sum`, or `min`, ...)

Comment: @trincot Thank you for suggestion. One row of ubd can just have one edd value to get from. I do not want aggregate value but to compute for each row of ubd so that result can be updated to new column of ubd.

Comment: So there is no possibility to get two edd values for one ubd? In that case it is OK, but you would need to select the ubd.id value as well, otherwise you cannot know which record to update.

Comment: You need correct indexes. You are probably missing some. Add your explain output. Apart from the inner query, that maybe can be optimized (I don't think it will get materilized now, and I would put it in a left join, but we need the explain output and your mysql version for that) and your missing aggregate your query looks ok.

Comment: you can speed up your query by adding index for the related fields

Comment: Move the last two AND's to a WHERE clause; they don't belong in JOIN..ON.  And provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scst: INDEX(merchant_type, service_category_id, id)
ubd:  INDEX(service_category_service_type_id, id)
edd:  INDEX(service_category_id)
c:    INDEX(used_balance_detail_id)
```

Look into changing the `not in ( select distinct ...)` into either `not exists(select *...)` or a `LEFT JOIN`.

The query has a potential flaw -- the `GROUP BY` does not list all the columns in the select, so the resultset is potentially random.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by and  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html